# how to get access control lists for a long UNC path, I am currently using Delimon library however it doesnt implement getaccesscontrol method?

Tags: c#

I am trying to fetch list of users having read and write permissions on files on a network shared folder. At times the length goes beyond 260 characters and I cannot use FileInfo class to GetAccessControl(). I use Delimon for this reason however Delimon library doesnt implement GetAccessControl(). Any alternatives?

Answer (score 2):

I know two possible alternative libraries:

https://github.com/alphaleonis/AlphaFS or http://alphafs.alphaleonis.com/

https://github.com/peteraritchie/LongPath

I just did a quick check of both regarding longpath-support and ACL managment functions:

```
FileSecurity fileSecurity = File.GetAccessControl(fileName);

foreach (FileSystemAccessRule ar in fileSecurity.GetAccessRules(true, true, typeof(NTAccount)))
{
    string account = ar.IdentityReference.Value;

    Console.WriteLine(account);
}
```

with `using System.IO` you get the normal behavior (exception with long paths)

If you switch to one of the above libraries:

```
using Alphaleonis.Win32.Filesystem;
```

or

```
using Pri.LongPath;
```

the above code snippets compiles and runs without exception even if the filename exceeds 259 characters.

I have no real experience with both libaries, but AlphaFS seems more complete and supports UNC paths (\\server\share\dir1\file1.txt)

In addition, AlphaFS is licensed under MIT (which is compatible with GPL, so it can be used in either commercial, but also GPL licensed projects).

LongPath is licensed under LGPL.

Comment: Thanks Rainer. I will try it. And let you know.